# Unit testing Spring 3 database methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit

I have abstract class that defines database methods, such as inserts and updates, and a concrete class that implements it. The database configurations (dataSource, DatabaseTarget etc) are defined as beans in context.xml-file.

The database with its methods work in Controller when I'm using Spring 3 anotations by

```
private AbsractClass a;
```

Constructor:

```
@Autowired
public Controller(AbstractClass a) {
    this.a =a;
}
```

...and a getter for a.

Calling database methods is done by

```
getA().insertValues();
```

But I would like to write Junit tests for my methods. Is there any example for this kind of situation? I have googled for hours.

Comment: Which methods? The DAO methods, or the controller methods?

Comment: Should there be any dependency on spring for writing dao tests? The data layer could be tested independently of the web layer, assuming you don't use any spring support for data access.
Also, should the controller directly access data related classes? Perhaps some service layer should be involved here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your controller methods without touching the database (which is the correct way), create a new class that extends the AbsractClass and pass it as argument to your Controller class, example:

```
CustomerController controller= new CustomerController(new InMemoryCustomerDao());
//call your actions and assert, all calls to the database will hit the InMemoryDao.
```

Another way is to use a [Mock Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) if you don't want to create extra fake classes in your project or you need to assert that these arguments are being correctly called.